# How to use $http inceptor to automatically attach the token to request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jwt, passport-local

I am developing a authentication mechanism

I am using nodejs for the sever side and on successful login i am generating jwt token

How to use that generated token on subsequent request from the client side built using Angularjs

*on successfully login i am redirecting the user to home page with the generated token, but i am not understanding how can i use the generated token back and front and serve  the api calls

Comment: Show what you have tried. Do you have the token on the client side already?

Comment: yes i have the token in the client side

Comment: router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json(401, { error: 'message' });
    }

    //user has authenticated correctly thus we create a JWT token
    var token = jwt.sign(user,'zendynamixy', {
      expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
    });

// return the information including token as JSON

    res.redirect("/?token=" + token);

  })(req, res, next);
});

Comment: ...by editing the question

Answer (score 0):

Store the token in a service, let's call it: authService.

then, in the .config of your module, inject $httpProvider and just add this:

```
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('yourInterceptor');
```

Then somewhere (in the same file or another, doesn't matter), declare a service call 'yourInterceptor':

```
angular
    .module('yourModule')
    .factory('yourInterceptor', yourInterceptor);

function yourInterceptor(authService) {
    return {
       request: function(config) {
          // config describe the call that will be made
          // you can modify the url, the headers...etc
          // for example
          config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + authService.myWebToken;

          return config;
       }
    }
}
```

Note that an interceptor can also be used to intercept requestError, response, responseError. see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: thanks for the quick reply i am generating the jwt token on server side and back to the client like this     res.redirect("/?token=" + token); how can i use this token in the request in client side

Comment: on successful login the req is like this https://localhost:8006/?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NjE4YjM1OTQ5ODdiZjNjMjY0MTg3MTQiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImVyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJGpma29JWThRTURRM0xzb3lXcWhXYU9Tdnd1WTJBYXBYZm5iLkp6Yk1ocXF1R1V1UXgxM2Z1IiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJlciIsIl9fdiI6MH0.JfXtewl0vyQ5BxQh2byQ_LwMngXFOMLps_0AQx1aGvE#/

Comment: When the user log in, in response send the jwt. On angular side, store it in a service (see my answer above), and then inject it in the header of each request. On server side, for each request, check for the jwb. You have some npm package to help you on the server side (I like this one: https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt), but that's another story, as your question was about client side ;)